# itextsharp joined pdf size too large

Tags: pdf, compression, size, itext, reduce

I have an asp.net (c#) web application.
I joined together some pdf files on serverside with itextsharp.
The result pdf is too large (>1M) to be downloaded in our environment.

I checked fonts list in Adobe Reader and Verdana font embedded 10 times. It could be a problem. I don't know why? I use iTextSharp PDFCopy for merging.

If I capture the file by fiddler and than print it out by bullzip pdf printer the size become the half (500KB)!!!

I can't figure out what bullzip pdf printer does to reduce the size???

All the joined pdfs are mosty text only a couple of small images.

Interesting when I try to copy/paste text from the original pdf I can, but I can't from the bullzip printed version (i get only rectangles when paste). That is no problem by the way because I don't need to edit or search by text, I only need to print it from the browser.

I need some .net library to do the same with the pdf before I send it to the browser.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You don't tell us how you merge the PDFs. Are you using `PdfSmartCopy`? If not, you're a craftsman who blames a tool instead of blaming his own ignorance...

Comment: I did use PdfCopy. I didn't know there is a "smart version". Thanks a lot! I will try and let you know about the result...